# Why should I use my own buffer for getline or similar functions?

Tags: c, buffer, getline

I was writing a program the other day where I used the `getline()` function and I realized something that I have never thought of before and haven't been able to find anything about it online.

According to the description of `getline` from the man page:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The `getdelim()` function reads a line from stream, delimited by the character delimiter.  The `getline()` function is equivalent to `getdelim()` with the newline character as the delimiter.  The delimiter character is included as part of the line, unless the end of the file is reached.
>
> The caller may provide a pointer to a malloced buffer for the line in `*linep`, and the capacity of that buffer in `*linecapp`.  These functions expand the buffer as needed, as if via `realloc()`.  If `linep` points to a `NULL` pointer, a new buffer will be allocated.  In either case, `*linep` and `*linecapp` will be updated accordingly.

Normally when I use this function I always malloc my own buffer and pass it into the getline funciton but after reading this I realized that this is not necessary as one will just be created.

My question is: Is there any reason why I should create my own buffer and then pass it into getline as opposed to just passing `NULL` and letting getline handle the buffer?

The only reason I could think of is if you want to exercise control over the size of the buffer but this doesn't seem right because it says it will resize the buffer as necessary.

When should I use my own buffer and when should I let getline handle the creation of the buffer?

Comment: What if you want to read lots of lines, and not pay for the `malloc`/`free` cost on every single one? I'd let `getline` allocate it, and then let it manage it for each subsequent read, then `free` it at the very end.

Comment: Ah I didn't think of reusing the buffer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: Is there any reason why I should create my own buffer and then pass it into getline as opposed to just passing NULL and letting getline handle the buffer?
A: Typically, no.  In some select situations, it makes sense to allocate before calling `getline()`.

1) Many `getline()` re-allocation schemes are liner.  That is it will allocate a buffer of N bytes (e.g. 256, 1k, 4k).  Then if that is not big enough, it will try 2*N, 3*N, 4*N, 5*N, etc.  If for some reason, code expects regularly large buffer needs, allotting a single large buffer before calling `getline()` will prevent `getline()` from repeated relocations of small buffers.  A potential, if dubious, efficiency improvement.

```
  size_t size = 10000;
  char *buf = mallc(size);
  ssize_t numchar = getline(&buf, &size, ...);
```

2) Should code need or have a working buffer available before calling `getline()`, it is fine to use it.

```
  size_t size = 100;
  char *buf = mallc(size);
  ...
  foo(buf, size);
  ...
  // No need for these steps
  // free(buf);
  // size = 0;
  // buf = NULL;
  ...
  ssize_t numchar = getline(&buf, &size, ...);
  ...
  free(buf);
```

3) Repeated calls. This include a loop that repeated calls `getline()`.  No need to free within the loop, wait until the loop is done.  @Alan Stokes

```
  // do not use this
  while (some_condition) {
    size_t size = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    ssize_t numchar = getline(&buf, &size, ...);
    foo(numchar, buf,size);
    free(buf);
  }  

  // instead, use this model
  size_t size = 0;
  char *buf = NULL;
  while (some_condition) {
    ssize_t numchar = getline(&buf, &size, ...);
    foo(numchar, buf,size);
  }  
  free(buf);
```

Q2: When should I use my own buffer and when should I let getline handle the creation of the buffer?
A2: Allocate your own buffer when code *certainly* needs or benefits from it.  Else let `getline()`  do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no reason, the buffer is `realloc`d as needed and you should `free` it yourself. So you can just pass `NULL` making sure that passed `length == 0`.
2. I don't see any situation where it would be good to use your own allocated buffer, you would use `malloc` anyway and that's what `getline` `getdelim` would use too.

Of course if you pass a large enough buffer you would prevent calling `realloc` on each `getline` but you can test with `valgrind` and for the most common cases there will be as few as possible calls to `realloc`.